# qlist - avoid memory leak

Tags: qt, qlist

```
typedef struct {
    char *u8_testStep;
    char *u8_functionTested;
    char *u8_testDescription;
    char *u8_expectedResponse;
    char *u8_packetTx;
    char *u8_packetRx;
    char *u8_passFail;
    char *u8_comment;
}T_testStepDetails;
```

list created for type `T_testStepDetails` :--

```
QList<T_testStepDetails>* testCaseStepslist = new QList<T_testStepDetails>();
QString strTemp;
T_testStepDetails *testStepMessageBuffer = new T_testStepDetails;
```

Allocating memory to indivisual element of `T_testStepDetails` :----

```
testStepMessageBuffer->u8_testStep = new char[strTemp.length()];
// copy value to the pointer
qstrcpy(testStepMessageBuffer->u8_testStep, strTemp.toStdString().c_str());
```

Append to the list :---

```
testCaseStepslist->append(*testStepMessageBuffer);
```

free memory:----

```
if(!list.isEmpty())
{
    qDeleteAll(list);
    list.clear();
}
```

So to free the memory above steps are enough to prevent memory leak `?`

Or for every structure of type `T_testStepDetails` in the list i have to free memory for the internal `char*` members for whome i have dynamically allocated memory `?`

Answer (score 3):

Note that you don't need to instantiate the list dynamically, Qt containers are explicitly shared for reading and can be even passed as value without a deep copy occurring. A `QList` created on the stack may even be a little faster due to the less indirection.

I also notice you are using a combination of plain dynamic allocation, plain array dynamic allocation as well as a reference counted container. While there is nothing particularly wrong with that, but it is better to decide whether you will be using the low level or high level constructs for the sake of uniformity, as Riateche mentioned, you can get away with using high level constructs all the way and completely avoid manual memory management considering you have no limitation not to use those... What you have now is just messy, even if not necessarily wrong.

Since the object you store in the list is not `QObject` derived, you can even get away with storing the actual elements instead a pointer to them (`QObject`s cannot be copied so you can only store pointers to them in containers), potentially in a sequential container to minimize wasted memory space and get even better performance. `QList` will even de-allocate and destroy (if there was anything to) all the instances when it fall "out of scope". In your current scenario, you use regular pointers, which have no destructor and naturally do not de-allocate their memory.

So, my suggestions:

- use `QString` instead of `char *`
- use `QScopedPointer<T>` instead of `T *` or just store actual instances (e.g. the value)
- use stack allocation wherever possible

This reduces the possibility for memory leaks to the minimum. Plus I think it is good to avoid the "pointer to list of pointers to structs of pointers to chars" scenarios - you are making it unnecessarily complex on the surface, with higher constructs all this complexity will be hidden from you and memory management will be automatic.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you are using Qt, it seems reasonable to replace `char *` with `QString`. This lets you get rid of the `char *` arrays memory deals. Then consider every case you allocate memory dynamically: may be you can use just stack-allocated objects. For example,

```
QList<T_testStepDetails>* testCaseStepslist = new QList<T_testStepDetails>();
```

on the first glance seems to be redundant. You can always pass the list by reference. As well you can `append` stack allocated objects to your list, it isn't nesessary to create it dynamically, then copy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `delete[]` on each `char*` you have created with `new[]`.

Consider using `QByteArray` or `QString` instead or `char*`.